# Why a value for an R object appears twice in a cbind output in R?

Tags: r, function, cbind

I was wondering how I could prevent the numeric value of object `eta` in my R code below from being repeated (as it does now) in the second row of my `cbind()` output and instead of that an `NA` be inserted in the second row?

**Here is my current `cbind` output:**

```
          Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value     Pr(>F)       eta
k          2 8.688793 4.3443964 5.47955 0.02038724 0.4773314
Residuals 12 9.514058 0.7928382      NA         NA 0.4773314(This one is repetitive! I want `NA` here)
```

**Here is my R code:**

```
k = gl(3, 5, 15)
y = as.vector(unlist(mapply(FUN = rnorm, n = rep(5, 3), mean = c(4, 5, 6))))
a = anova(aov(y ~ k))
eta = a[, 2][1] / (a[, 2][1] + a[, 2][2])
cbind(a, eta)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure eta value is being recycled. You may try 
    `cbind(a, eta = c(eta, NA))` to avoid the recycling.